# Yii change class of errorHandler in config/main.php

Tags: php, yii

I've created a Custom error handler class (CMyErrorHandler) that extends from CErrorHandler.

However when I configure the class of the errorHandler component in config/main.php to be CMyErrorHandler, Yii still seems to be using the old CErrorHandler class.

```
    'errorHandler'=>array(
        'errorAction'=>'site/error',           
        'class' => 'application.components.CMyErrorHandler',
    ),
```

How can I manage to use my Custom error handler? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you already verified if your `CMyErrorHandler` is extending `CErrorHandler` correctly?

Maybe this link can help you: view_findpost_*p*_155043">http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/32160-custom-error-logging/page_*view*_findpost_*p*_155043

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of my problem. I's not possible to extend CErrorHandler and just override the two methods I needed (handleError and handleException), because these methods use a private variable un CErrorHandle which is not accessible in the extended class CMyErrorHandle. I believe this is due to a bad design in Yii's CErrorHandle class (though I must say I absolutely love the framework). Therefore I opted to copy paste the whole class and make the changes I needed in both methods. After these everything worked as expected.